# How to copy case class object?

Tags: scala, tree

This is what I have tried

```
 sealed abstract class Tree
case class NewNode(left: Tree,center: Tree, right: Tree) extends Tree
```

I just want to copy the whole object

```
scala> val treeM = treeD.copy_
<console>:16: error: value copy_ is not a member of NewNode
       val treeM = treeD.copy_
                     ^
```

The above does not work

```
scala> val treeM = treeD.copy(_,_,_)
treeM: (Tree, Tree, Tree) => NewNode = <function3>

scala> println("Tree M == Tree D: %s" format (treeM == treeD).toString)
<console>:18: warning: (Tree, Tree, Tree) => NewNode and NewNode are unrelated: they will most likely never compare equal
       println("Tree M == Tree D: %s" format (treeM == treeD).toString)
```

How to write proper object copy?

Comment: Could you please explain why you would want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `copy` without any arguments.

```
val treeM = treeD.copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, but there is no reason to copy immutable objects.